# what is the difference between 送る and 贈る?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I noticed that both are pronounced the same way and that both have approximately the same meaning "to send". Is there a slight nuance in the usage of both of these versions of "to send"?
I'm thinking that one might be more related to sending a person somewhere and the other might be more related to sending an object somewhere. Or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is rather huge.

「[送]{おく}る」 means to physically "send by mail or a delivery service."  What you can send must be a tangible item.  It can also be a person that you 送る to some place by a mode of transportation.

「[贈]{おく}る」 means "to present a person with something".  That something can be either tangible or intangible.  You can 贈る a favorite saying of yours or your own poem to someone.  The focus is on the "presenting", not on the actual "sending".

「贈り[物]{もの}」 means a "gift".